# How to get a specific language translation using pybabel

Tags: python, gettext, python-babel

Most of the time, using Babel's `gettext()` or `_()` is with a current locale set within the current context, so that the target language is implicit, it is not passed as an argument to gettext().

However, is there a way to get the translation of a phrase in a given target language, such as:

```
message = gettext('Hello there', language='es')
```

The original gettext does not have this possibility, but is there any other API that would achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the plain gettext API, use environment variables:

```
import os

os.environ['LANGUAGE'] = 'en'
message = gettext('Hello there')
```

For OO gettext it goes like this:

```
import gettext

fr = gettext.translation('yourdomain', languages=['fr'])
es = gettext.translation('yourdomain', languages=['es'])

fr.install()
// use French ...
es.install()
// use Spanish ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this might help some people, but in my case I'm in a web server multi-user environment using Flash, so I doubt the os.environ trick would do it.    Actually there are tricks to switch locale in Flask via   `ctx = _request_ctx_stack.top` then `ctx.babel_locale = Locale.parse(language)`, but I was looking for a true API to babel, with locale as argument.

Comment: The os.environ trick should work everywhere. An API call with the locale as an argument is very unlikely to exist because the underlying C API does not have anything like that, and that is on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Flask-Babel](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Babel/), you can use `force_locale` from its [Low-Level API](https://flask-babel.tkte.ch/#flask_babel.force_locale):

```py
from flask_babel import force_locale

with force_locale('en_US'):
    send_email(gettext('Hello!'), ...)
```